# Getting the page sizes of a PostScript document

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I want to get page size of each page of a PostScript document in a simple program or shell script.

Is there any program or library that can get the page sizes. (Like pdfinfo, but dealing with PostScript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No doubt, there's some program for that, but you can try using Ghostscript:

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=nullpage -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
-c '/showpage{currentpagedevice /PageSize get{=}forall showpage}bind def' \
-f test.ps
```

But then you may need to filter out any warnings or DSC comments. E.g. one of test file I found gave me this:

```
%%[ ProductName: GPL Ghostscript ]%%
(Warning: Job contains content that cannot be separated with on-host methods. Th
is content appears on the black plate, and knocks out all other plates.)
595.28
841.89
%%[Page: 1]%%
%%[LastPage]%%
```

Putting some markers into your redefined `showpage` procedure may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use PostScript level 2, you can use `currentpagedevice`:

```
/pagewidth  currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get def
/pageheight currentpagedevice /PageSize get 1 get def
```

Comment: The answer is duplicated with the accepted one. And it's not matching what I asked "... in a simple program or shell script".

Comment: Fair enough.  I think I actually meant to post this in answer to a different SO question asking more or less the same thing, minus the script part.  On the answer they mixed up 0 and 1.  Unfortunately, I mixed up the question :(